# My lines don't go where they are supposed to go

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

The lines should go top right corner, where (a,0) is. I couldn't work it out. I'm using Eclipse 3.65.

[image]

```
public class Ikibin extends JFrame{

int a = 400;
int b = 600;

public Ikibin()
{

    setTitle("Tutorial");
    setSize(a,b);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, 0, b);
    g.drawLine(a/4, 0, a/4, b);
    g.drawLine(a/2, 0, a/2, b);
    g.drawLine(3*a/4, 0, 3*a/4, b);
    g.drawLine(0, 0, a, 0);
    g.drawLine(0, b/4, a, 0);
    g.drawLine(0, b/2, a, 0);
    g.drawLine(0, 3*b/4, a, 0);
}


public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Ikibin i = new Ikibin();
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like they are, but they're going to the 0,0 of the WINDOW, not the canvas.

Comment: But the canvas ends in (a,0), and the line also goes to (a,0). How can this happen? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 0):

Your setting it to be 0 which is where it is but the X is still a /4 or a / 2 or so. So basically you are making it go in select places. How the code is written is where they will go if you want them all in the top right corner then you would just leave x as 400. Or in your case A = 400.